# An issue regarding Eigenvalues function

Tags: matrix

Can anybody please kindly explain to me why the members of the output vector produced by the following example are not equal to zero?

```
mm = 1000;
Clear[i, j, ss, EIG];
ss = ConstantArray[0, {mm, mm}];
%%% "Generating a random sparse matrix (ss)";
For[i = 1, i < (mm) + 1, i++,
  For[j = 1, j < (mm) + 1, j++,
    If[i == j,
     ss[[i,j]] = (RandomReal[{-Mod[{i + j}, 2][[1]],Mod[{i + j}, 3][[1]]}, 1])[[1]];
     ];
    If[Abs[i - j] == 1,
     ss[[i,j]] = (RandomReal[{-Mod[{i + j}, 2][[1]],Mod[{i + j}, 3][[1]]}, 1])[[1]]+0.2;
     ];
    If[Abs[i - j] == 2,
     ss[[i,j]] = (RandomReal[{-Mod[{i + j}, 2][[1]],Mod[{i + j}, 3][[1]]}, 1])[[1]]-0.1;
     ];
    If[Abs[i - j] == 3,
     ss[[i,j]] = (RandomReal[{-Mod[{i + j}, 2][[1]],Mod[{i + j}, 2][[1]]}, 1])[[1]]+0.1;
     ];
    ];
  ];

EIG = Sort[(Select[Cases[(Eigenvalues[ss, -10]), _Real], # > 0 &]),Less];
EIG - Sort[(Select[Cases[(Eigenvalues[ss, -10]), _Real], # > 0 &]),Less]
```

For instance, one run of this example leaded to this vector:

```
{8.41341*10^-16, -2.57433*10^-15, -1.9082*10^-16, -8.32667*10^-17}
```

I am wondering why the output vector members are not zero! You can test this example on your PC. THNAKS.

Comment: They are equal to zero, within numerical tolerances, and that is the key whenever you are using numerical algorithms.

Comment: Just to elaborate on @rcollyer's comment: You can get rid of the small non-zero terms by using `Chop` or by using higher precision (see `SetPrecision` for example).

Comment: @sebhofer you are absolutely correct, but I would like to add a caution against using `Chop` indiscriminately. Since your are truncating the numbers, you are effectively adding in rounding errors, if done to early in the calculation, and can seriously impact the results. So, `Chop` away, but do it at the end.

Comment: @rcollyer, thank you for your comments, but still I cannot see where the problem is. Whatever we get from Eigenvalues function is stored in EIG vector, but when we take Eigenvalues results from EIG, a slight difference appears. I am wondering what is the source of these small values in the output vector. I have same problem in a big program in which these values are not as small as this example and cannot be resolved by chop.

Comment: @Nasser, if you repeat this example for larger values of mm (like mm=2000), do you get zero again?

Comment: @makmaak the problem is the numbers are not exact, numerically. One of the causes is you're changing bases from base 10 to base 2, which cannot represent the same set of numbers in a finite manner. For instance, 1/10 in base 2 has a repeating, non-terminating representation, like 1/3 does in base 10. So, they are truncated, and generate errors. Also, there are numerical errors that can and do show up as small, non-zero results. Since your results are on the order of `$MachinePrecision`, they are very likely ignorable, hence the advise of using `Chop`.

Comment: @makmaak (cont'd) Also, because they are of the order of `$MachinePrecision`, they cannot be trusted to be meaningful. They are quite literally at the limits of what we can know. Additionally, the subtraction you are performing is just revealing the numerical errors, and _nothing_ else.

Comment: @makmaak Which Mathematica version are you using? FWIW I also get `0.` with V 9.0.1 under Linux 64bit.

Comment: @makmaak It appears I did not read far enough into your prior comment. With any numerical calculation, errors accumulate, and can increase beyond the default values for `Chop`. Try changing the second argument to [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html) to something larger than `10^-10`. I have worked with simulations where 2 decimal digit accuracy was the norm, so your comfort level may vary.

Comment: @sebhofer I am using V 8.0.4.0 on windows 7, 64 bit. Do you get zero for larger values of mm as well?

Comment: I get zeroes for the case mm=1000, mac os mathematica 9.01

Comment: @bill s Could you please try it for larger values of mm?

Comment: yes, it works fine for 2000 and 3000. I tried to run 10000 but after an hour I got bored.

Answer (score 2):

[Too long for a comment...]

If I understand correctly, the claim is this. Taking Eigenvalues[...,-10] multiple times, on the same matrix, gives results that differ by an ULP or so. If this is indeed the claim, then (1) the post does a really good jjob of disguising it, and (2) this probably can happen for a couple of reasons.

One is if the algorithm uses randomized starting values for any iteration. Since I do not see this behavior on Linux machines I'll bet against that. The other has to do with certain subtleties of the OS as to when 64 bit vs 80 bit register arithmetic is used. Some of the remarks [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Feb/msg00117.html) might help to explain this.

--- edit ---

By coincidence I was looking through an old bug report. The gist was that in some Intel MKL library code one can get two different numeric eigen-results that are typically close together. It does seem to depend on byte boundary alignment, which I believe affects whether or how 80-bit floats registers get used.

--- end edit ---

Comment: I think this is indeed what the post claims. @randomized starting values: It is very interesting for me that you say that, as it confirms a suspicion I had a few years back, regarding eigenvalue computation in Matlab where you could actually see this behavior. I just never followed up on that.